# Sybase Subgroup Order By

Tags: t-sql, sybase, sap-ase

I'm trying to join a sub query but as the table contains no unique row_id and I need the most recent record of a specific type, I want to do an Order by Date Desc and get the Top 1 from that, but it doesn't seem allowed in Sybase ASE.

I put together a small sample to show kinda what i'm trying to do.

```
CREATE TABLE #test_users (USER_ID CHAR(9), USER_CK INT)
INSERT INTO #test_users (USER_ID, USER_CK) 
          SELECT 'QA0000001', 123000010
UNION ALL SELECT 'QA0000002', 123000020
UNION ALL SELECT 'QA0000003', 123000030
UNION ALL SELECT 'QA0000004', 123000040
UNION ALL SELECT 'QA0000005', 123000050

CREATE TABLE #test_records (STAT_TYPE CHAR(3), USER_CK INT, MOD_DT DATE, PLAN_ID CHAR(1))
INSERT INTO #test_records (STAT_TYPE, USER_CK, MOD_DT, PLAN_ID) 
          SELECT 'ADD', 123000010, '8/1/2017', 'A'
UNION ALL SELECT 'TRM', 123000010, '6/1/2018', 'A'
UNION ALL SELECT 'ADD', 123000010, '6/1/2018', 'B'
UNION ALL SELECT 'ADD', 123000020, '5/1/2017', 'A'
UNION ALL SELECT 'TRM', 123000020, '9/1/2018', 'A'
UNION ALL SELECT 'ADD', 123000030, '3/1/2018', 'A'
UNION ALL SELECT 'ADD', 123000040, '4/1/2018', 'A'
UNION ALL SELECT 'ADD', 123000050, '1/1/2018', 'B'
UNION ALL SELECT 'TRM', 123000050, '7/1/2018', 'B'
UNION ALL SELECT 'ADD', 123000050, '7/1/2018', 'A'


--Want to know everyone that has ever been in Plan A, and what their last status type was.
--Should return 
--  QA0000001, A, TRM, 6/1/2018
--  QA0000002, A, TRM, 9/1/2018
--  QA0000003, A, ADD, 3/1/2018
--  QA0000004, A, ADD, 4/1/2018
--  QA0000005, A, ADD, 7/1/2018
SELECT u.USER_ID, r.PLAN_ID, r.STAT_TYPE, r.MOD_DT FROM #test_users u
LEFT JOIN #test_records r 
    ON PLAN_ID = 'A'
    AND u.USER_CK = r.USER_CK
```

Thanks for any help you could provide.
Mike

Comment: How do you determine `last status type` when you  have 2 entries in `#test_records` with the same `max(MOD_DT)` (eg, 123000010 + 6/1/2018; 123000050 + 7/1/2018)?  what would you expect for QA0000001 if the second record for 123000010 has a STAT_TYPE=C' (instead of current 'A')

Comment: I only want to retrieve those records where the PLAN_ID = 'A'

Comment: so what you're looking for isn't "everyone that has ever been in Plan A" but rather "everyone who is currently in Plan A"?  so you'd ignore someone who was in Plan A last year but who is currently in Plan B

Comment: I need the last status for everyone who was ever in Plan A.

For example:  
#test_record 123000010 was added into Plan A on 8/1/2017 on 6/1/2018, they switched over to Plan B.
The Application generated a Term record for Plan A and also an Add record for Plan B on that same day.

The Plan A report should show just the 1 last record returned for 123000010 which would be 6/1/2018, TRM

Hopefully I explained it better.
Thanks

Comment: unfortunately we're back to one of my original questions ... which STAT_TYPE to use if there are 2x entries on the max(date); using your example: 123000010 has 2x records on 6/1/2018 ... TRM/A, ADD/B ... it's not clear (to me) how to determine, **programatically**, which STAT_TYPE to use (sure, **you** know to pick the TRM record, but how someone w/out your knowledge know which STAT_TYPE to use when multiple STAT_TYPEs on the same (last) day)

Comment: There is only 1 record on 6/1/2018 for that user where the PlanID = A  I don't want to look at any where PlanID is not A, so that ADD/B should be ignored.  Perhaps what I'm asking isn't possible.

Comment: well, now we're back to my follow-on question ... you're only interested in records with PLAN_ID='A' ... so, ignore all records where PLAN_ID != 'A' ... which means we're only interested in accounts with a current PLAN_ID='A'